# Regex search text between multiple equals and comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below logic to extract data between equals and comma. I wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this. Any suggestions please?

```
import re


s = "param1 = This is a, test message. Hello, world., param2=msg 2 {} in view, param3=field1,field2,field3"

pattern = "param1\s*=(.*),\s*param2="
substring = re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
print(substring)

pattern2 = "param2\s*=(.*),\s*param3="
substring2 = re.search(pattern2, s).group(1)
print(substring2)

pattern3 = "param3\s*=(.*)"
substring3 = re.search(pattern3, s).group(1)
print(substring3)
```

Output

```
 This is a, test message. Hello, world.
msg 2 {} in view
field1,field2,field3
```

Comment: Since a comma may or may not indicate the end of a parameter, how can I know that `"param2=msg 2 {}..."` isn't part of the value of `param1`? Is `=` guaranteed to never appear in a parameter name or value?

Comment: @Locke That is correct ```=``` is not going to appear in param name or value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the regex I came up with: `(\S+)\s*=(.*?)(?=(?:,\s*\S*\s*=)|$)`. Now I'm doing this off memory so this may not be completely correct, but I believe you can then do something like this:

```py
pattern = "(\S+)\s*=(.*?)(?=(?:,\s*\S*\s*=)|$)"

for key, value in re.findall(pattern, s):
    print("Key: \"{}\" Value: \"{}\"".format(key, value))
```

[How this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/MwKBZt/1)

Comment: Thanks, could you please add some explanation?

Comment: In the link regex101 provides a breakdown of each element of the regex. Essentially, `findall` finds all instances of the pattern and you can iterate over the groups of each match. The way I wrote the regex, it captures a non whitespace sequence of characters followed by `=` as the first group. It then captures as few characters as possible up to (positive lookahead) either the end of the input or the next key and equals sign.